# Angular 2 nested navigation with new router

Tags: typescript, angular

How can I achieve nested navigation? I had this with the previous router.

```
{ path: '/admin/...', component: AdminLayoutComponent }
```

It seems that from rc1 angular2 doesn't support this.

From the documentation.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Notice that the path ends with a slash and three trailing periods (/...).

That means this is an incomplete route (a non-terminal route). The finished route will be some combination of the parent /crisis-center/ route and a route from the child router that belongs to the designated component.

EDIT:
These are my routes

```
//AppComponent
@Routes([
    { path: '/admin-login', component: AdminLoginLayoutComponent },
    { path: '/admin', component: AdminLayoutComponent },
    { path: '/edit', component: EditReportLayoutComponent },
    { path: '/', component: WebLayoutComponent },
])

//WebLayoutComponent
@Routes([
    { path: '/details/:id', component: DetailsComponent },
    { path: '/applications', component: ApplicationsComponent },
    { path: '/statistics', component: StatisticsComponent },
    { path: '/addreport', component: NewReportComponent },
    { path: '/register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: '/account', component: AccountComponent },
    { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/feed', component: AllFeedComponent },
    { path: '/', component: MapComponent }
])
```

EDIT: Added a minimum example on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4TAd436l91zGX2emsxEF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `/...` they are not needed in the new router if you have child routes. There are still a few issues with the new router and not all features are available. One (pitfall is that the order of routes is relevant (<strike>will be fixed</strike> by design). The most specific (longest) route should come first and the more generic one last (like `/`, or `*`)

Comment: So this would be the solution    { path: '/admin/', component: AdminLayoutComponent },

Comment: I get EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'statistics'. Available routes: ['/admin-login', '/admin', '/edit', '/'].   None of the child routes is respected :)

Comment: When doing what? A routerLink? How does it look like?

Comment: [routerLink]="['/statistics']" for example

Comment: Where is this routerLink? Please try `[routerLink]="['/','statistics']"`

Comment: This router link is in WebLayoutComponent

Comment: Ok, then `[routerLink]="['statistics']"`

Comment: nope still doesnt work here is the simple plunker examle i made http://plnkr.co/edit/4TAd436l91zGX2emsxEF?p=preview

Comment: Plunker doesn't work for me today :-/. The routes should be sorted so that the most specific are first (as already mentioned). You might try to not use routes with path `''` or `'/'`. They might work (don't know) but I would first try with routes like `/xxx` and if that works you can still try `''` or `'/'`.

Comment: Ok i found a solution child routing obviously doesnt work.             <a [routerLink]="['/admin/main']">Admin Main</a> this is the only way. This is the example in plunker i provided

Comment: Running plunkers doesn't work for me since yesterday :-/ Currently you need to order routes in `@Routes(...)` so that the most significant routes come first and least significant routes like `/` last (this will be fixed). I saw that this isn't the case in 2 of your components.

Comment: I tried that first time you said. It really doesnt work. Can you try opening plunker in another browser ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to debug this issue just yet. I can take a closer look again in a few days. The order of the routes might not solve your actual issue but its still necessary until https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8420 is fixed.

Comment: Moving the route definition { path: '/second', component: SecondComponent } into app.component.ts worked for me.

Comment: Thats cool but that is not a child route than. Correct me if i am wrong. And what about different templates for different pages than?? Before we had /.. that doesnt also seem to work